# Solving the recurrecne relation $a_{n}=a_{n-1}^{3}a_{n-2}^{2}$

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations

So I thought of using substitution $b_{n}=\log_{2}a_{n}$ and what I have is that for the given initial values $a_{0}=a_{1}=2$ they become $b_{0}=b_{1}=1$ and my recurrence relation changes to:
$$
b_{n}=3b_{n-1}+2b_{n-2}
$$
Testing this recurrence relation for $n=2,3,4$ gives:
$$
b_{2}=3b_{1}+2b_{0}\implies b_{2}=9+4=13
$$
$$
b_{3}=3b_{2}+2b_{1}\implies b_{3}=3\cdot13+4=43
$$
$$
b_{4}=3b_{3}+2b_{2}\implies b_{4}=3\cdot43+2\cdot13=155
$$
However, I can't seem to see the clear pattern here. Is there something wrong with my attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you have to solve the recurrence for the $b_n$. The characteristic polynomial roots are $r_\pm=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{17}}2$, so $b_n=Ar_++Br_-$; initial conditions give $A=\frac{17-\sqrt{17}}{34}$ and $B=\frac{17+\sqrt{17}}{34}$, so
$$b_n=\frac{(17-\sqrt{17})((3+\sqrt{17})/2)^n+(17+\sqrt{17})((3-\sqrt{17})/2)^n}{34}$$
and $a_n=2^{b_n}$.